# How to use like clause in Laravel when we are using Raw SQL ?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel raw sql query feature. And have to perform a like query. There are so many joins and checking in this code. So it's better to use raw SQL. Everything is working fine. But when I use the like , there's an error.

```
$Stars = DB::select('select v.videoid,s.seriesshortname, v.videotitle, v.VideoShortName, v.VideoImagepath, v.Views, v.Likes, v.Dislikes, v.Rating, v.videocategory, v.lastupdated,v.videocategory,v.seriesid,v.genreid,v.studioid from tblvideo v, tblpornstarvideo pv,tblseries s,tblpornstar p where v.videoid = pv.videoid and v.seriesid = s.seriesid and upper(v.Active) = \'Y\' and pv.psid = p.psid and pv.psid = :id and (v.site = 1 or v.site=3) and v.videotitle like \':letter%\' order by v.videotitle limit 6 offset :offset', ['id' => $id, 'offset' => $offset]);
```

Please check the like code. (v.videotitle like \':letter%\')

And please tell me how to make that working.
I followed the documentation here. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database

Comment: It's not better to use the raw SQL. It's actually worse. It makes the PHP code less readable to any poor soul which may be called upon to maintain it in the future. Performance-wise it's probably the same as when you build a query with fluent.

Comment: @apokryfos Normally it's best to do it with the query builder, but there are occasions where that can't get the job done. I'm not sure if this is the case, but it's a chance to learn how.

Comment: @apokryfos There are so many joins and also conditions. I also like to use only standard eloquent queries. But I tried and it's so hard. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the wildcards to your variable, not the query, and don't add the quotes. You're also not passing in the letter variable:

```
$Stars = DB::select("select v.videoid,s.seriesshortname, v.videotitle, v.VideoShortName, v.VideoImagepath, v.Views,
v.Likes, v.Dislikes, v.Rating, v.videocategory, v.lastupdated,v.videocategory,v.seriesid,v.genreid,v.studioid
from tblvideo v, tblpornstarvideo pv,tblseries s,tblpornstar p
where v.videoid = pv.videoid and v.seriesid = s.seriesid and
upper(v.Active) = 'Y' and pv.psid = p.psid and pv.psid = :id and (v.site = 1 or v.site=3)
and v.videotitle like :letter order by v.videotitle limit 6 offset :offset", ['id' => $id, 'letter'=> $letter.'%', 'offset' => $offset]);
```

Comment: Great. This solved my issue :) Thanks a lot buddy :)